# Modify url in Firefox

Tags: firefox, url-modification

I want to intercept and modify a url in firefox so that part of it turns into a "better" version of the website.

More specificity I want to turn this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/shorts/(video-id)
```

into this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=(video-id)
```

I want a general solution so I can do this to more sites than just youtube.

Comment: It's really unclear what you are trying to do here. Are you asking about writing a browser extension? Are you trying to intercept URLs in the address bar, in links in HTML documents, somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer, not completely what I wanted but good enough:

https://git.bradleylaboon.com/lb.laboon/youtube-shorts-disabler

also as:

https://addons.mozilla.org/sv-SE/firefox/addon/youtube-shorts-disabler/

It is so simple I can do a new addon for every site if need be.

The only problem I have is that it does not work if I follow a link/left klick on a YouTube short within YouTube, apparently Firefox does not report that the URL has changed to the plugin. A simple page refresh (F5 in my case) fixes that.